# Error en DecimalFormat no admite numeros double sin coma

Tags: android

Quiero formatear las variables double de esta manera

```
        DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat( "###,##0.00 €" );
        cuota.setText(form.format(numerodouble));
```

Funciona bien excepto cuando el numerodouble no tiene parte decimal, es decir, solo su parte entera.

numerodouble = 5.5 se formatea a 5.50 €
numerodouble = 6 se formatea a 0.00 € o cualquier otra cosa pero no como debe de ser a 6.00  €

¿ Como lo puedo hacer ?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿`numeroDouble` está declarado como `int` o como `double`?

Comment: Acabo de replicar tu ejemplo y funciona sin ningún problema. Tanto pasando un `double` con decimales, como sin. Incluso pasando directamente un `int`. Parece que debes tener el error en otro sitio.

Comment: Al parecer el error no está en el código que de DecimalFormat sino más bien en numerodoble he probado el código y me muestra el resultado esperado.